# How to handle data with missing timesteps to create Time series model?

Tags: python, time, time-series, missing-data, arima

The data has a series with Time_id as index. The index is not a Date time index, which makes it possible to fix missing time intervals.
My question is:

1. Can I forecast this series with ARIMA?
2. If yes, how can I handle the missing Time_ids?
   As per the below image, I want to fill the gaps in Time_id. So I need to add additional rows with Time_id 8,9 and values as zero.
   This is a huge data many possible missing time intervals.
   If anyone can help me fix this it would be great. The sample image is in the link below.

[Time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxj3Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could impute the missing values. Add the missing time steps as NaNs to the time series and then use an imputer as described here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

It will impute the missing values depending on the strategy you use, e.g. with the mean value of the series or the mean of the last and next known value etc.